# screen orientation

Tags: android, landscape, portrait

Hi 
 M new to android.I faced a problem i.e in landscape mode i need a layout view which doesnot have  some feilds which are present in the portrait mode.I have created a layout for landscape view in such a way.In the activity i have given the conditions like if portrait display some feilds some hide.its working properly actually...first when i go from portrait to landscape it is giving what i want...but when i go to portrait mode its stopping the application.please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the log output (e.g. in eclipse) say? Why does is stop?

Answer (score 2):

You can make two different layouts and put them in layout-port and layout-land respectively.
And make sure that you have mentioned android:configuration = "orientation" in your manifest for that activity. Try it if i have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the advice by Kantesh may be backwards. As explained in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), if you include android:configChanges="orientation" in the manifest, then the correct resource (from layout-port or layout-land) won't be automatically loaded. Instead, leave out mention of orientation from the manifest. Then, you do not need to worry about `onConfigurationChanged()` (don't override it). The system will automatically shut down the activity and then restart it, binding the appropriate version of configuration-dependent resources. Handling configuration changes yourself is (again, according to the docs) only a last resort to deal with performance issues that cannot be handled in other ways.