# Android: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and orientation changes with different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I've got an activity which should have two rather different layouts depending on whether the user holds it in landscape or portrait mode.

In onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), I store a lot of information and extract this in onCreate() if it exists, to restore the user data.

I've got a method to determine if the phone is currently in portrait or landscape mode - if getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() is larger than getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), then it's in landscape.

In my portrait layout xml file, I have a few image views which are not present in the landscape layout xml file. In onCreate(), I check if we're in portrait, then initialise and modify these if so. If we're in landscape mode, I don't.

This all works fine for switching from portrait to landscape, but then when switching back into portrait, my code that is executed only for portrait mode gives a null pointer exception - it can't find the view elements.

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apps.hyperview/com.apps.hyperview.PopUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at com.apps.hyperview.PopUp.onCreate(PopUp.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4800):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!
r3mo

**EDIT:**

Popup.java section causing problems:

```
// Check orientation. If we're in portrait...
if( isInPortrait() )
{
        spacer_above = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display_popup_spacer_above);
        spacer_above.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    // THIS IS CAUSING THE NULLPOINTER
        spacer_below = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display_popup_spacer_below);
        spacer_below.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else;
```

The portrait version of the layout file contains these 'spacers', but the landscape version does not. Is this how orientation changes and different layouts should be handled when using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()? The code all works fine going from portrait to landscape, but when going back to portrait, I get the NullPointerException.

EDIT 2:

isInPortrait() seems to be working fine - I will change this however. The reason I'm not just making the views invisible is that the structure of the layout is significantly different in landscape. Obviously, this landscape layout is working fine - the error occurs when going from portrait to landscape and then back to portrait.

All help is appreciated!

EDIT 3:

I've now changed how I'm doing this to have the same layout file in layout-port/ and layout-land/, and making the view elements that I don't want in landscape View.GONE. It would certainly still be good to get input on this problem - it seems like a very powerful feature of android to be able to have *completely* different layouts for landscape and portrait.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see the code. The stack trace seems to indicate the null exception occured in your PopUp.java file, in the onCreate method, at line 147.

Comment: "I've got a method to determine if the phone is currently in portrait or landscape mode - if getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() is larger than getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), then it's in landscape." -- why not use the `orientation` field on a [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) object? After all, that is what Android will use to determine which layout to load.

Comment: Don't trust isInPortrait() at all. And why not set these views invisible in the XML?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816768/screen-orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can put the portrait layout in res/layout-port, the landscape version of the layout in res/layout-land, and a default (for square screens, I suppose) in res/layout. The system automatically (and reliably) determines which version of the layout to use. Is there a reason that you aren't doing that?

Comment: This is what I'm doing, and I'm using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to save user data during an orientation change. During onCreate(), I need to intitialise/configure a few views (the spacers), which are only present in the layout-port.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write your code to test whether findViewById is returning null, which it will when you try to find one of the portrait-only views when in landscape mode.